# Word exports empty non-working Bookmarks additionally to the working ones I generated

Tags: microsoft-word, pdf, bookmarks

Currently I am working on a bigger Word file with many chapters. I export this file to PDF with the following options:

[image]

The export works fine but when I decide to display all exported Bookmarks in my PDF program some strange additional Bookmarks appear:

[image]

I have no idea why this happens. Of course I could just disable bookmark export but those are handy when working correctly. Does anyone know how to get rid of the non-working ones?

Those are my bookmarks:

[image]

Chapter1 - Chapter6 are generated by me, the rest is generated by Word (?)

Comment: What do you see in Word when go to Insert tab, in the Links group and click Bookmark where you get a list of all bookmarks. Are there any unwanted bookmarks? Note that there is an option to view hidden bookmarks

Comment: There are the bookmarks I generated by hand (with text selected, I learned that this is the better way) and a lot of generated bookmarks that seem to be the problem. I deleted all of them but when saving the next time those are regenerated. Any idea by whom or how to find out?

Comment: Does your word file has a table of contents with clickable (hold ctrl) hyperlinks? `_Toc***` is an indicator for this. You can unlink them with Ctrl+Shift+F9

Comment: I just saw that you selected `Create bookmarks using headings`. But if there are already correct bookmarks set by your TOC, you should use them. Switch this option and see how it fits your needs

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I thought this option is for creating PDF bookmarks. But apparently it creates Word bookmarks.

Answer (score 3):

I had this happen to me today.  We had track changes on in the document, and there were deleted headings that were hidden.  When I deleted those tracked changes and saved as a pdf again, the bookmarks were looking good.

Comment: For me, I had to accept the changes to remove those 'ghost' headings

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have blank text marked as Heading 1 which often happens when you copy and then delete a paragraph of that style.

Check the headings in the document and remove any you find, this feature can help with that: [image]